# How can I ignore scope when I pass a method as parameter?

Tags: c++

I have one class SFAPin, and there's one method:

```
SFAPin::addListener(void (*)(SFAPinEvent&), uint8_t){};
```

But when I tried pass one method of another class for this method:

```
void InitialState::lightChange(SFAPinEvent &event){};

light.addListener(&this->lightChange, SFAPinEvent:PIN_CHANGE);
```

I got:

*error: no matching function for call to 'SFAPin::addListener(void (InitialState::*)(SFAPinEvent&), uint8_t)'
note: candidates are: void SFAPin::addListener(void (*)(SFAPinEvent&), uint8_t)*

if lightChange is a static method works well using:

```
light.addListener(lightChange, SFAPinEvent:PIN_CHANGE);
```

But I don't want a static method

How can I resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: It's not just scope, it's an entirely different type of function. You need to decide if the function `lightChange` needs to be called on an `InitialState` object or not (does it use the values inside it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `addListener()` expects, is a *pointer to function*. The argument, you pass into, is a *pointer to member function*. You can resolve this by either passing a function or by adding a method, which expects a pointer to member function

```
SFAPin::addListener(void (InitialState::*)(SFAPinEvent&), uint8_t)
```

But then, you must also add an object pointer, which can be used with the given method, maybe something like

```
SFAPin::addListener(InitialState &state, void (InitialState::*)(SFAPinEvent&), uint8_t)
```

Comment: InitialState extends SFAState and work well
SFAPin::addListener(void (SFAState::*)(SFAPinEvent&), uint8_t)
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use bind or lambda, to adapt a member function into the signature you need.
e.g.

```
bind(&InitialState::lightChange, this, _1);
```

Details [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers)

Or, using lambdas in C++11

```
addListener(
  [&] (SFAPinEvent &event)
  {
    lightChange(event);
  },
  SFAPinEvent:PIN_CHANGE
);
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples/14189561#14189561)

The static compiled because

> "static member functions do not require an actual object to be
>   invoked, so pointers-to-static-member-functions are usually
>   type-compatible with regular pointers-to-functions." (from [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/memfnptr-vs-fnptr.html))