# Can we create an Adapter patterns using function pointers?

Tags: c++

I was trying to have an Adapter class, which has a Function Pointer (say `fnPtr`). And based on different Adaptee classes the `fnPtr` will be assigned with corresponding adaptee`s function.
Following is the code snippet:

```
class AdapteeOne
{
public:
    int Responce1()
    {
    cout<<"Respose from One."<<endl;
    return 1;
    }
};

class AdapteeTwo
{
public:
    int Responce2()
    {
    cout<<"Respose from Two."<<endl;
    return 2;
    }
};
class Adapter
{
public:
    int (AdapteeOne::*fnptrOne)();
    int (AdapteeTwo::*fnptrTwo)();
Adapter(AdapteeOne* adone)
    {
    pAdOne = new AdapteeOne();
    fnptrOne =  &(pAdOne->Responce1);       
    }
Adapter(AdapteeTwo adtwo)
    {
    pAdTwo = new AdapteeTwo();
    fnptrTwo =  &(pAdTwo->Responce2);
    }
void AdapterExecute()
    {
    fnptrOne();
    }
private:
    AdapteeOne* pAdOne;
    AdapteeTwo* pAdTwo;

};

void main()
{
Adapter* adpter = new Adapter(new AdapteeOne());
adpter->AdapterExecute();

}
```

Now the problem I am facing is in the `main()` function. I am not getting any way to call Adapter`s function pointers (`fnptrOne`and`fnptrTwo`).
I am getting:

> error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

along with the previous error message. This could mean that `&` operator is not able to create a function pointer out of `pAdOne->Responce1`.

Does it mean that we can`t have a function pointer in some`ClassA`which could point to a non-static function present in another`ClassB`?

Comment: Just as a hint, you might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). I explain how to use them in [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples/14189561#14189561).

Comment: Also you may want to read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning a member function pointer, you assign it the *class* member function pointer, as in `AdapteeTwo::Responce2`.

So it should be e.g.

```
fnptrTwo =  &AdapteeTwo::Responce2;
```

You use the object when *calling* the member function pointer:

```
(pAdTwo->*fnptrTwo)()
```

This last statement calls the function pointed to by `fnptrTwo` in the `pAdTwo` object, so `pAdTwo` will be `this` inside the called member function.

Comment: I tried the same as follow:
fnptrOne =  &(AdapteeOne::Responce1);
fnptrTwo =  &(AdapteeTwo::Responce2);
But got error saying: "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.
The error statement is very confusing. Please comment.".
I can see the error is coming because both the functions are member functions, so implicit parameter "this" is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Anitesh I'm not saying anything about how you declare the function pointers, it's how you assign and call them that you have to change.

Comment: Please have a look on my first attempt code:
`class Adapter
 {
 public:
  int (AdapteeOne::*fnptrOne)(void);
  int (AdapteeTwo::*fnptrTwo)(void);
 Adapter(AdapteeOne* adone)
  {
  fnptrOne =  &(AdapteeOne::Responce1);
  this->*fnptrOne();
  }
 Adapter(AdapteeTwo adtwo)
  {
  fnptrTwo =  &(AdapteeTwo::Responce2);
  }
 };
void main()
 {
 Adapter* adpter = new Adapter(new AdapteeOne());
 
 (pAdTwo->*fnptrTwo)();

 
 }`
The above code was not working and giving error C2064, mentioned above. Had i misunderstood what you said?

Comment: @Anitesh But you haven't declared any variables `pAdTwo` or `fnptrTwo` in the `main` function, so yes that will give you compilation errors. Also in the constructor for `AdapteeOne` you forgot the parentheses around the object (and it's not `this` you should be calling the function on but `adone`) and function pointer, which will also cause an error.

Comment: @Anitesh I really recommend you to read my comment about `std::function` and `std::bind`. It will make your life much easier in the end if you start using them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and for the information about the above mentioned two functions. It is working fine now.