# calling C++ class member functions using a functional template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to be able to call a member function (eg. `doSomething()` in class `testClass` ) outside the class using some sort of functional template. In short, be able to call a non-static member function somewhat in this manner, `functionCaller(t.doSomething)` from `main()`.

Say I have a C++ class like:

```
class testClass {
public:
    testClass()
    {
        value = 0;
    }
    int prod(int i)
    {
        value *= i;
        return value;
    }
    int doSomething()
    {
        value = prod(10);
        return value;
    }

private:
    int value;
};
```

My functional template looks something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename ret>
ret callFunction(T t, ret (T::*func)()) {

    // checkSomePermissionsHere()
    return t.func()
}
```

If I try to use this template in the following manner:

```
int main()
{
    testClass t1;
    callFunction(t1, &testClass::doSomething);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: no member named 'func' in 'testClass'
return t.func(a);
         ^
```

What is the correct way to call this member function (`doSomething`) on object `t1` through the `callFunction` method? I want to implement `callFunction` as part of a general API which does some checks before executing the provided fucntion.

I'm using clang/LLVM 3.5 for my compiler.

Comment: `return (t.*func)();`

Comment: Ahh... thanks. That's worked.

Comment: You might be interested in [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), it makes handling these issues much easier.

Comment: That would be really nice @JoachimPileborg, can you please expand a bit? If I understand nicely, I might be able to improve my answer! :D

Comment: @gsamaras See e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples/14189561#14189561).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, I did improve my answer, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
return t.func()
```

to this:

```
return (t.*func)();
```

and it should compile and execute fine.

---

As Joachim Pileborg stated, you could use [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) and [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/). In that case, your code could look like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class EventHandler
{
    public:
        void addHandler(std::function<void()> callback)
        {
            std::cout << "Handler added..." << std::endl;
            // Let's pretend an event just occured
            callback();
        }
};

class testClass {
public:
    testClass()
    {
        value = 0;
        EventHandler handler;
        handler.addHandler(std::bind(&testClass::doSomething, this));
    }
    int doSomething()
    {
        value = prod(10);
        std::cout << "I did something!\n";
        return value;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    testClass t1;
    return 0;
}
```

The code above was based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples/14189561#14189561).

Comment: I'm not sure I have access to functional. Do you know if clang 3.5 supports it yet? Otherwise std::functon would have been a good idea. Thank for the suggestion.

EDIT: I see it has been supported for some time now

Comment: Thank you for letting us know @AdwaitDongare!