# C++ Event template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, events

I would like to write a C#-like C++ event class like this :

```
template< typename ListenerType >
class Event
{
private:

    std::vector< ListenerType * > m_aListeners;

public:

    void operator += ( ListenerType * pListener )
    {
        m_aListeners.push_back( pListener );
    }

    void operator -= ( ListenerType * pListener )
    {
        std::vector< ListenerType * >::reverse_iterator revIter = m_aListeners.rbegin();
        for( ; revIter != m_aListeners.rend(); ++revIter )
            if( revIter == pListener )
            {
                m_aListeners.remove( revIter );
                break;
            }
    }
};

class DataReceivedEvent : public Event< DataReceivedListener >
{
public:

    void Trigger( const byte_t * pData )
    {
        for( size_t nI = 0; nI < m_aListeners.size(); ++nI )
            m_aListeners[ nI ]->OnDataReceived( pData );
    }
}
```

The problem is that it forces me to write a `Trigger` method that always does the same thing (iterate and call handlers) for each event type since different events can have a different list of parameter, and for each event, the associated handler type has a mehod with a specific name.

I don't know much about C++11, but i have the feeling that it would be possible to avoid rewritting the Trigger method for each event type using templates.
But i can't use C++11, so i wonder if there is a way, using older C++ version, to do that, in a type safe way.

EDIT : I thought about creating a hierarchy of event data classes, i.e `template< typename ListenerType >::Data` and `DataReceivedEvent::Data : public template< typename ListenerType >::Data` so that i can have a Trigger method always taking a single argument, i.e `virtual void Trigger( const Data * pData )`. But I still have the problem that it needs to call a specific method in the event listener.

Comment: Can you use Boost? Because then you can use [Boost function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/function.html) and [Boost bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) libraries.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your previous comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples/14189561#14189561). It seems to be supported in VS2005 so I will have a look at this.
And I do not want to use boost because my targeted platforms are Android (which is OK) and Windows CE (which is not very well supported by boost).

Comment: Ho unfonrtunately function and bind are not supported by VS2005 :( But maybe i can still find a compatible way to do it with what exists in `<functional>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates and operator overloading for this as well. When you assume that the `ListenerType` implements the `operator()` you can implement it like this (the example also uses [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). You can use arbitrary amount of arguments):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template< typename ListenerType >
class Event
{
private:

    std::vector< ListenerType * > m_aListeners;

public:

    void operator += ( ListenerType * pListener )
    {
        m_aListeners.push_back( pListener );
    }

    void operator -= ( ListenerType * pListener )
    {
        auto revIter = m_aListeners.rbegin();
        for( ; revIter != m_aListeners.rend(); ++revIter )
            if( revIter == pListener )
            {
                m_aListeners.remove( revIter );
                break;
            }
    }

    template<typename... Params>
    void operator()(Params... data) {
        for (auto l : m_aListeners) {
            (*l)(data...);
        }
    }
};

class DataReceivedListener {
public:

    void operator()(const char* pData) {
        std::cout << pData << std::endl;
    }

};

class DataReceivedEvent : public Event< DataReceivedListener >
{
public:
};


int main() {

    DataReceivedEvent e;
    DataReceivedListener l1;
    DataReceivedListener l2;
    e += &l1;
    e += &l2;

    e("Hello");
}
```

Unfortunately, C++11 does not introduces [Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29). If you had this ([constraints in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)) you would get some more help by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But unfortunately i can't use C++11.

Comment: OK. You can just remove the dots and it should work with C++98