# C++/(Qt) pointer to any object with specific method

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

How do I do to call a specific method present on all classes from an other (TranslationManager) class ? 
I simplified a lot the code. I just want to call the `setTranslationText` of any class from TranslationManager.

These are to take in consideration:

1. All classes have a `setTranslationText` method
2. We should call setTranslationText of any class from TranslationManager by using the pointer to the class

   ```
   class Interface
   {
      ...
      public:
        void setTranslationText(QString translatedString); 
   }

   class AnyOtherInterface
   {
      ...
      public:
        void setTranslationText(QString translatedString); 
   }

   ...

   …
   Translationmanager::Translationmanager(){
      AnyClass = Interface; // Pointer to Interface Class
      AnyClass->setTranslatioNText("Text");

      AnyClass = AnyOtherInterface; // Pointer to AnyOtherInterface Class
      AnyClass->setTranslatioNText("AnotherText");
   }


   …
   ```

Comment: It can't be done without that method being `virtual` in a common base and `AnyClass` being a pointer to that base.

Comment: Your code simplification is nonsense. The `Interface` and `AnyOtherInterface` classes share no common base class, thus there's no way to have one pointer point to them all (other than `void*`). You'll have to make the simplification work, and ensure that base classes and method signatures are exact. For example `method(QString foo)` is silly, you should have `method(const QString &foo)`

Comment: @KubaOber I really have basics knowledge on C++ (I would like to know more about it). If you have an online C++ course, be free to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't precise about what I wanted. I finally found the best solution to my problem: **callback**.

Solution found on: [C++ class member callback simple examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples/14189561)

```
std::vector<std::function<void(std::string,std::string)>> callbacks;

template<class T> void addTranslationText(T* const object, void(T::* const mf)(std::string,std::string)){
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    callbacks.emplace_back(std::bind(mf, object, _1, _2));
}

...

// Call callback
callbacks.at(0)(std::string("arg1"), std::string("arg2"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a template

```
template <typename T>
void setTranslationText(T* t, const QString &translatedString)
{
    t->setTranslationText(translatedString);
}
```

That way you wouldn't need an interface class just to inherit for this one (or however many) methods. Then the template would only compile if for a given class instantiation they had a `setTranslationText` method defined. The way you'd use it is

```
Translationmanager::Translationmanager()
{
    setTranslationText(Interface, "Text");                // Pointer to Interface Class    
    setTranslationText(AnyOtherInterface, "AnotherText"); // Pointer to AnyOtherInterface Class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Cory's answer: If you're using C strings to initialize `QString`, you shouldn't depend on the implicit conversion - instead, make your use case explicit:

```
template <typename T>
void setTranslationText(T* t, const char *translatedString) {
  t->setTranslationText(QString::fromUtf8(translatedString));
}
```