# Try to create C# style event access modifier in C++ using std::functional and std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to create C# style event handling, i.e expose += operator for everybody and expose `Invoke` method only for the containing class.

I'm using std::functional and std::bind as explained here to create callback mechanism:
[C++ callback using class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-callback-using-class-member/14189561#14189561)

To enable invoking the event only from containing class, 
I created `Event::Invoke()` method private, and then I create a friend class of `Event` called `ClassWithEvent` thats has protected method `InvokeEvent` which calling `Event::Invoke`.
All the inheritanced classes of `ClassWithEvent` can invoke the event using base class `InvokeEvent` method.

Additionly, I want to enable events to have different kind of args, so I create base class `EventArgs` which can be extended by other king of args.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace placeholders;

class EventArgs
{
};

class Event
{
    friend class ClassWithEvent;

public:
    void operator+=(function<void(const EventArgs &)> callback)
    {
        m_funcsList.push_back(callback);
    }

protected:
    void Invoke(const EventArgs & args) const
    {
        for (function<void(const EventArgs &)> func : m_funcsList)
        {
            func(args);
        }
    }

    vector<function<void(const EventArgs &)>> m_funcsList;
};

class ClassWithEvent
{
protected:
    void InvokeEvent(const Event & event, const EventArgs & args)
    {
        event.Invoke(args);
    }
};
```

For exaple, I have `ApplesTree` class with `AppleFallEvent` event,
I have `ApplesCollector` class which should be notified about falling apples:

```
class AppleFallEventArgs : public EventArgs
{
public:
    int size;
    int weight;
};

class ApplesTree : public ClassWithEvent
{
public:
    Event AppleFallEvent;

    void triggerAppleFall(int size, int weight)
    {
        AppleFallEventArgs args;

        args.size = size;
        args.weight = weight;

        ClassWithEvent::InvokeEvent(AppleFallEvent, args);
    }
};

class ApplesCollector
{
public:
    void HandleAppleFallEvent(const AppleFallEventArgs & args)
    {
        cout << "Apple size is " << args.size << "weight is " << args.weight << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ApplesTree applesTree;
    ApplesCollector applesCollector;

    applesTree.AppleFallEvent += bind(&ApplesCollector::HandleAppleFallEvent, &applesCollector, _1);

    applesTree.triggerAppleFall(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Well, I try to compile this and get the following errors:

> C2672 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

and

> C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

I can't look out where is the problem because this errors belongs to std code and its really hard to deal with it.
Any way, I found that if I removing the usage of `Event::operator+=()` the compile is successfull.

Can someone point out what is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: [Poco library](https://pocoproject.org/documentation.html#slides) implement this kind of [event handling](https://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf) so you can check their source code. And here is other [approach for making EventBus with custom arguments and strong types](https://github.com/gelldur/EventBus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `Event` know which particular args it will use. Note that `using namespace std;` is a bad idea. I've also replaced the `bind` with a lambda.

```
// no empty class EventArgs

template<typename EventArgs>
class Event
{
    friend class ClassWithEvent;

public:
    void operator+=(std::function<void(const EventArgs &)> callback)
    {
        m_funcsList.emplace_back(std::move(callback));
    }

private:
    void Invoke(const EventArgs & args) const
    {
        for (auto & func : m_funcsList)
        {
            func(args);
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::function<void(const EventArgs &)>> m_funcsList;
};

class ClassWithEvent
{
protected:
    template<typename EventArgs>
    void InvokeEvent(const Event<EventArgs> & event, const EventArgs & args)
    {
        event.Invoke(args);
    }
};

class AppleFallEventArgs
{
public:
    int size;
    int weight;
};

class ApplesTree : public ClassWithEvent
{
public:
    Event<AppleFallEventArgs> AppleFallEvent;

    void triggerAppleFall(int size, int weight)
    {
        AppleFallEventArgs args;

        args.size = size;
        args.weight = weight;

        InvokeEvent(AppleFallEvent, args);
    }
};

class ApplesCollector
{
public:
    void HandleAppleFallEvent(const AppleFallEventArgs & args)
    {
        std::cout << "Apple size is " << args.size << "weight is " << args.weight << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ApplesTree applesTree;
    ApplesCollector applesCollector;

    applesTree.AppleFallEvent += [&](auto & args){ applesCollector.HandleAppleFallEvent(args); };

    applesTree.triggerAppleFall(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't think to use template... '^_^. By the way this line `void InvokeEvent(const Event & event, const EventArgs & args)` should be `void InvokeEvent(const Event<EventArgs> & event, const EventArgs & args)`

Comment: @DawidDrozd It's worse than I thought, `std::function` only has `operator==` to compare to `nullptr`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that event handler method that you are trying to bind does not match event handler function because `HandleAppleFallEvent` takes `const AppleFallEventArgs &` instead of `const EventArgs &`.

Also there are a lot of unnecessary copying, for example `for (function<void(const EventArgs &)> func : m_funcsList)` can be replaced with `for (function<void(const EventArgs &)> & func : m_funcsList)`.

Comment: Oh, I tried to make it like that beacuse I want to enable different kinds of args, how can it be done?

Comment: @OdedRadi You just need to make sure that function signature is compatible.

Comment: I got it, but I want to have generic type for args, that can be changed to other concrete args depends of the Handler class.